# I have no idea what to do with the error int cannot be dereferenced.

Tags: java

mind taking a look at this code? it gives me an error and I cant figure out what to do. Its for a class and any help would be appreciated. I have to make a lottery program with three digit numbers randomly generated individualy and then the user can win in a number of combinations. Refer to the code for a clarification.

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Lottery 
{ 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
//declare and initialized variables and objects 
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

String lotteryNum = ""; 
String userGuess = ""; 

for(int tries = 0; tries >= 0; tries++) 
{ 

int randomNum1 = (int)(Math.random() * 10); 
int randomNum2 = (int)(Math.random() * 10); 
int randomNum3 = (int)(Math.random() * 10); 

int computerNum1 = getNumericValue (randomNum1.charAt(0) ); 
int computerNum2 = getNumericValue (randomNum2.charAt(1) ); 
int computerNum3 = getNumericValue (randomNum3.charAt(2) ); 

String randomNum = "" + randomNum1 + randomNum2 + randomNum3; 

System.out.print("Please enter three numbers:"); 
int num1 = in.nextInt(); 
int num2 = in.nextInt(); 
int num3 = in.nextInt(); 



if (num1 == computerNum1 && num2 == computerNum2) 
{ 
System.out.println("You win!"); 

} 
else if (num2 == computerNum2 && num3 == computerNum3) 
{     
System.out.println("You Win!"); 

}  
else if (num1 == computerNum1 && num2 ==computerNum2 && num3 == computerNum3) 
    {
    System.out.println("Sorry, You Lost");
    }
    }}}
```

Comment: solution: don't try to dereference an int. It's not an object.

Comment: how would i fix it then?

Comment: The error is your answer in itself. `Integer` is an object but `int` is a primitive type. Dereferencing `int` will always give you error

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out that it looks like the `randomNums` are supposed to be one digit numbers *anyway*, so those three lines also seem pointless, not just invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work: `randomNum1.charAt(0)`

An int is not a String and not even an object, and so you can't call methods on it. It's a primitive and like all primitives has no methods. It just *is*.

Instead I suppose that you could use int division and mod operators to get what you want, but to be able to tell for sure, you should post your actual assignment instructions because your description of your ultimate goal is not clear to me.

If all you want are 3 random numbers, 0 to 9, then just use the numbers that you already have, and no need to try to manipulate them further.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `charAt` on an `int`, because it's not a string.  Try:

```
String.valueOf(randomNum1).charAt(0)
```

Comment: `toString()` on an int? You're still dereferencing primitives then.

Comment: `String.valueOf(randomNum1).charAt(0)`. index > 0 and you're on your own!

Comment: Ack. I hate programming. This would work with cyber-neural telepathy.